# Apache won't run binary cgi

Tags: apache, cgi, binaryfiles

I've successfully run a Hello World perl cgi script, but I can't get a binary file (compiled from golang) to run.  Apache just serves it as a download.  I've scoured the internet looking for answers, and while it seems other people have had similar problems, the solutions aren't working.  I'm also not getting any error messages in the log, so I have no idea why it's not working.

The relevant lines of my httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule !mpm_prefork_module>
    LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
...
ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/srv/http/cgi-bin/"
...
<Directory "/srv/http/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
     Options +ExecCGI
    SetHandler cgi-script
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

I'm using Apache 2.4.41 on Archlinux.  The output of the binary when run from the shell is:

```
Content-type: text/html

SHELL=/bin/bash
WINDOWID=...
```

listing all of the environment variables. The permissions on the file are -rwxr-xr-x, so it should be executable no matter who runs it.  the file extension is .cgi, but that shouldn't even be relevant because it's in the directory marked ExecCGI, right?

Is there something I'm missing?  It seems like Apache is running some sort of filter on the files that I'm not aware of?